# mails being marked as spam

Tags: email, sendmail, smtp

I configured my own mail server using sendmail for our application . Mail server is used to send automated mails when a user registers at our site . I was able to implement this successfully, but users who are registering using gmail account , automated mail message for registration are being marked as spam. This is not a issue for yahoo users.

Following can be seen in message header of the mail marked as spam.

```
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 103.x.x.x is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of Admin@validdomain.com) client-ip=103.x.x.x;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 103.x.x.x is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of Admin@validdomain.com) smtp.mail=Admin@validdomain.com
Received: from www.validdomain.com ([192.168.x.x])
```

Kindly suggest how to resolve the issue . The application just went live and it is critical for us to resolve the issue.

Comment: Note that if you are sending *large* amounts of e-mail, particularly in large batches (like for example newsletters), it's usually better to outsource that to some provider which specializes in such tasks. They know how to set things up so that the messages don't get treated as spam unnecessarily.

Answer (score 8):

You're sending email to gmail accounts from this address:

> Admin@validdomain.com

The domain "validdomain.com" you're sending from does not have an SPF record setup for it. You have 1 of 2 options:

1. Change the server's mailer so that its outgoing mail uses a domain that is allowed
2. Set up an SPF record for validdomain.com

You can use this tool to see what domains are allowed to send email for your domain.

- [Beveridge Hosting - SPF Test](http://tools.bevhost.com/spf/)

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2003/security-message-hygiene/Sender-Policy-Framework.html) on how to setup a SPF record. SPF records are just DNS TXT records that contains rules saying which hosts are allowed to send email for a given domain.

Comment: The mail server I am using in this case does not have a registered domain name. If i configure the mail server in a different host which has a registered domain name but without having a SPF record , will it work for me i.e will it bypass the spam filter rules.